# Will stimulus create an opportunity to raise interest rates?

Tags: interest-rate, federal-reserve

I don't know very much about economics myself, but I have noticed two concerns repeated often lately.  One is that the recent injection (?) of trillions of dollars of stimulus money into the economy will result in inflation.  The other is that interest rates are very low (compared to historic values) and that the fed has no room to lower them in case of future economic crisis.

Could it be that these two situations will cancel each other out?  Might the inflation give the fed room to increase interest rates, and so everything settles back down to "normal"?  Could that even be their plan?

Answer (score 1):

With massive deficit spending, it's possible to have slow growth and high inflation at the same time. Then the central-bank wants lower short-term interest rates to support the economy but the central-bank must raise short-term interest rates to control inflation.

The central-bank only sets overnight bank rates as longer-term interest rates are set by demand in the bond market. However, if the central-bank wants to control longer-term interest rates, without raising short-term interest rates, they can buy their own bonds. The obvious question concerns the limit of central-bank bond buying. Now a central-bank bond-buying might just be a gaming of a historically supported bond market and that would explain why all countries can't do it.

Several different situations can occur but I am suggesting inflation as represented by high longer-term interest rates and then raising short-term interest rates controls inflation which increases demand for longer-term bonds and which then lowers longer-term market interest rates.